# CoreData multiple Fetch Request

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have a core data models and data storage for devices. each device contains colours, storage and price. Is there anyway i can filter already fetch request (array of all the devices from DB). i need to implement filter functionality for devices containing colour , storage and price. filter can be apply multiple times, means once you apply filter for colour it will only show those devices containing those colour + respective storages and vice versa. I can filter it once using predicates but for applying another filter i need to call query again for getting all devices and applying respected filter. Is there any other way around, so when i get filtered data from fetch request, i can apply other filter on that same filtered data. or the way i'm doing its the only the way to work in core data.

this is how i'm filtering my data based on the filter selected:

```
-(void)getAllDevicesDetailBasedOnFilter{
    NSMutableArray *predicateArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    //DevicesCatalogueSkuDetails
    isColorSelected = YES;
    isBrandSelected = YES;
    isStorageSelected = YES;
    isPriceSelected = YES;
    if (isPriceSelected) {
        NSPredicate * pricePredicate =  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY skuDetails.priceWithVat >= %.f AND ANY skuDetails.priceWithVat <= %.f",minimumPriceValue,maximumPriceValue];
        [predicateArray addObject:pricePredicate];
    }
    if (isBrandSelected) {
        NSPredicate * brandPredicate =  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"brand = %@", @"Samsung"];
        [predicateArray addObject:brandPredicate];
    }

    if (isColorSelected) {
        NSPredicate * colorPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY skuDetails.color CONTAINS[cd] %@",@"Green"];
        [predicateArray addObject:colorPredicate];
    }

    if (isStorageSelected) {
        NSPredicate * colorPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY skuDetails.storage CONTAINS[cd] %@",@"256"];
        [predicateArray addObject:colorPredicate];
    }

    NSPredicate *compoundPredicate =  [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicateArray];
    [[CoreDataManager sharedInstance] fetchWithEntity:@"DevicesCatalogue" Predicate:compoundPredicate success:^(NSArray *fetchLists) {
        if(fetchLists) {

        }

    }failed:^(NSError *error) {

    }];

}
```

Comment: Store `fetchLists` as a local property, and use that for a second filter.

Comment: how can i do this ? can you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this using a local property for `fetchLists`

```
@property NSMutableArray fetchLists;

- (NSPredicate *) getFirstPredicate {
    // create your initial predicate here
}

- (NSPredicate *) getSecondPredicate {
    // create your second predicate here
}

- (void) fetchEntities {
    [[CoreDataManager sharedInstance] fetchWithEntity: @"DevicesCatalogue" predicate: nil 
        success: ^(NSArray *result) {
            if(result) {
                self.fetchLists = result;
            }
        } 
        failed: ^(NSError *error) {
            // handle error
    }];
}
```

And then from where ever you want to fetch and filter your data do something like:

```
[self fetchEntities];
NSArray *firstFilteredArray = [self.fetchLists filteredArrayUsingPredicate: getFirstPredicate];
NSArray *secondFilteredArray = [firstFilteredArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate: getSecondPredicate];
```

etc.

Or use a compound for your first and second predicate to filter the original `fetchLists`.